# Adding line-height style to a label in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, label

In my webpage there is label having multiple lines of text.
I need to add line-height property to that label in asp.net.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways to do this.
1) add a style for this. and give cssClass for that label.For example,

```
.line
{
  line-height:150%;
}
```

And add the class to your label.

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" cssClass="line" />
```

2) Add style in code behind

```
Label1.Style.Add("line-height","150%");
```

Change the line-height value to whatever you want

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
LabelID.Style.Add("line-height", "100px")
```